# Is there a SQL Server equivalent for Lucene's concept of Filter Queries?

Tags: sql-server

Lucene has a method of "filter queries," which are pre-queries which "whittle down" the domain of content, and then the *actual* query is only applied to the result of that pre-query.

For instance, if I had a complex query, but I only wanted it applied to the content published this year, I could add a filter query to my query which basically cut the entire content set down to just the content published this year, then applied my query to that. The entire domain of content is therefore whittled down to a subset, then *that* is queried.

Is there an equivalent in SQL?  Is there a way to dynamically "section off" part of the database, based on specific criteria, and then query against the remaining content only?

I'm pretty sure I could do it using temporary tables, like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM content WHERE year_published = 2014
SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE foo = bar
```

I'm quite sure this would work, but I'm not sure of the performance implementations of it, and it means I can't use regular SQL -- I'd have to run everything through a stored proc which encapsulates the temporary table logic (which means Entity Framework is probably out).  (And, yes, I could use a WHERE clause too, but, again, there's a lot of queries at work here...)

Every single query in this application should be filtered by permissions. Any user is only allowed to return data based on an over-arching, row-level permissions scheme, and every query they make on the database should be filtered by that scheme.

Is there a more graceful way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I addressed exactly this problem in my recent Budgeting and Forecasting application. An all key table DepartmentUser specified the accessible departments for each user of the system, and an inline table-valued function *AccessibleDepartments()* returned the set of Department ID's for which the system function [*session_user*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177587.aspx) was equal to UserID. By inner-joining all queries to this function on DepartmentID one obtains the required filtering.

If you require setting Read and Write privileges separately, that can either be done by using a separate table or adding a bitfield to the table DepartmentUser.

By:

- Putting all base tables in a schema that is inaccessible to logged-in users; and
- Creating a parallel (and accessible) schema that automatically
  performed this inner join and otherwise mirrored the base-table
  schema through identically named views

it was ensured that even *ad-hoc* queries had access rights properly enforced. Ownership chaining ensured that stored procedures in the second schema worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a sub-query (also called a **derived table**):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM content 
    WHERE year_published = 2014 
) filter
WHERE foo = bar
```

which can also be written as a **common table expression (CTE)**:

```
WITH filter AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM content 
    WHERE year_published = 2014 
)
SELECT *
FROM filter
WHERE foo = bar
```

If you want this to be repeatable without having to include the text for the filter in every query, you can do this with a **view**:

```
CREATE VIEW Filter AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM content 
    WHERE year_published = 2014;
```

And then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Filter
WHERE foo = bar
```

You can also set up a *materialized view*, which can improve performance if the data for the filter changes infrequently.

How all this applies to your permission scheme will depend on how your actual permissions are stored in the database, and on how you intend on meshing that with other queries.